# Trouble Configuring Subdomain on Digital Ocean

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, domain

I've just setup a Ubuntu droplet on Digital Ocean, and I'm having trouble pointing my subdomain to the droplet IP. The main domain is working just fine (it points to a different droplet). When I set the A record for the subdomain (pointing to the correct IP) and try to access the website, I get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED, although DNS propagation seems fine (I checked it at DNS Checker). Then I set the NS record for the same subdomain, pointing to the same nameservers which the main domain is pointed to, and now the error on the page is DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN. Also, when I set the NS record, the A record went crazy according to DNS Checker. I'm sorry, I'm really confused, this is the first time I've done this.
[This is how the records are set currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAh4B.png)

Answer (score 1):

Your initial configuration that just had an A record for `app.example.com` pointing to the new droplet IP was correct. The additional NS records you added were unnecessary.

The connection refused message you got with the initial configuration likely points to a non-DNS related config issue on your droplet unless you typo'd the IP address in the A record. Check firewalls. Check that the web server is running and on the port you expect.

Comment: What should I check for on the firewall? I'm really lost, sorry...

Comment: Check that port 80/443 are allowed.